# Java ArrayList with various types of Objects

Tags: java, list, iteration

I have `CardType1` and `CardType2` that extends `Card`, and an `Area` that has an `ArrayList` of Card. This array will be filled with `CardType1` and `CardType2` objects, but I need to eventually access them like:

```
for (CardType1 card : this.cards) { ...
```

An overview:

```
public class Area {

    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    ..
}

public class Card {..}

public class CardType1 extends Card {..}

public class CardType2 extends Card {..}
```

How can I iterate over only *one* of the subtypes in my `List<Card> cards` list?

Comment: good so far, and what is the question?

Comment: Where do you need access like that? If it doesn't make sense to have a heterogeneous list than don't have one.

Comment: Thinking a little outside the box, you could partition your arraylist in such a way that you additionally store a pivot element, and keep everything before that element of type CardType1 and everything after it of CardType2. This will require some sorting and updating the arraylist on each insert and remove operation though, but it will save you the time of iterating over the elements you dont want.

Comment: That's a good solution @G.Bach since it avoids `instanceof` and `isAssignableFrom` calls.

Comment: @Brian it does, I actually don't know if those operators are slow, though. It also avoids iterating over elements he doesn't actually want to process. Whether it's a suitable solution for him will depend on whether he makes frequent changes to the arraylist or whether the number of iterations over a specific type of card is large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it this way, because the type of object in cards, is `Card`, not `CardType1`:

```
for(CardType1 card : this.cards){ ...
```

You can however do this:

```
for(Card card : this.cards) {
    if (card instanceof CardType1) {
        CardType1 card1 = (CardType1) card;
        // do something with the card1
    } else {
        CardType2 card2 = (CardType2) card;
        // do something with the card2
    }
 }
```

What I am doing here, is iterating through the cards, as you were (except my type is the most general type to both besides `Object`). Then I check if the card is of type `CardType1`, or `CardType2`, using the `instanceOf` operator and cast it to that type, then handle it.

Answer (score 2):

You will only be able to iterate through each item as a `Card`. If you were able to iterate using `CardType1` then you would have an error when you encountered a card of type CardType2.

For what you want you will have to check whether `card` is an instance of `CardType1` or `CardType2` and then cast `card` appropriately:

```
for (Card card : this.cards) {
    if (card instanceof CardType1) {
        CardType1 cardType1 = (CardType1) card;
        // do something with cardType1
    }
    else if (card instanceof CardType2) {
        CardType2 cardType2 = (CardType2) card;
        // do something with cardType2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers by Dominic and Nathan are on the mark. If you're using Guava, you can use [`Iterables.filter(Iterable, Class)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29) as a shortcut:

```
for (CardType1 card : Iterables.filter(cards, CardType1.class)) {
    ...
}
```

From the documentation:

> Returns all instances of class `type` in `unfiltered`. The returned
>   iterable has elements whose class is `type` or a subclass of `type`.

Comment: Nice, but does this call filter on every iteration? My java is rusty.

Comment: +1, and it only calls `filter` once for the whole iterator, but `filter` _will_ essentially call `instanceof` on _every member_ of the given iterator. Guava is a must for any sufficiently complex project :)

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra Not sure I understand your question - the call delegates to `Iterators.filter` which returns a custom `Iterator` that skips elements not assignable to the type. [(source)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#line.758)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
cards.add(new CardType1());
cards.add(new CardType2());

for(Card card : this.cards){ 
   // card can be any thing that extends Card. i.e., CardType1, CardType2
   if(card instanceOf CardType1){
       //do cardType1 things
    }
   else if(card instanceof CardType2){
      // do CardType2 things
      }


}
```